# tying together the ways controllers and directives interact

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

I've read a lot over the last couple of days about the connections between directives and controllers. I've made a few observations but am having trouble putting them all together and could use a little guidance.

There are about four or five ways I've seen controllers and directives commingle.

Given:

```
angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('ctrlName', function($scope){
   $scope.someVar = "some value";
});
```

I've seen directives and controllers interact and be attached to one another the following ways:

1) Chained together with a dot

```
myApp.controller('ctrlName', function($scope){
   $scope.someVar = "some value within controller";
})
.directive('drtvName', function(){
   return {
     scope: {
       someVar: 'some value within directive'
     }
   }
});
```

2) controller specified as a method of a directive. How does this interact with the controller above if it is part of dot-chaining (like #1)

```
myApp.directive('drtvName', function(){
   scope: {/*not sure what it means when this is simply an empty object*/},
   controller: function(scope){
    /*is this completely separate from myApp.controller('name', function(){});*/
   }
});
```

3) controller is specified as name of separate controller within app. I'm not really sure how the two `scope`s would mix

```
myApp.directive('drtvName', function(){
   controller: 'ctrlName',
   scope: {
     connectedToCtrlScopeOrJustHTMLView: 'dunno'
   }
});
```

4) here's a new one. the controller is required as a parent controller. When I was tinkering with this, I couldn't even get it to work using the chaining method, so I'm not sure when it would be useful

```
myApp.directive(drtvName', function(){
   scope: {},
   require: '^myParentController' //not sure what scope will be one line about with this option
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The interactions you list there vary in many ways, but I'll try to summarize them here:

1. This illustrates creating a module and adding a directive and controller to that module.  They aren't interacting with each other in this instance, but instead with the module itself.  The return value of `.directive` and `.controller` is the module, so that's where the chaining comes from.
2. In this case, you are defining the controller function of a directive.  To answer your question there, yes, that is a completely different controller with the way you have it, but....
3. To segue into your next point, you can define a controller on a module like you do in #1 and then use it in your directive:

In your module:

```
module.controller('myController', function () {...});
```

In your directive:

```
controller : 'myController'
```

This makes things like unit testing a directive super easy, as well as a solid separation of concerns.

4. This is when a directive needs to communicate with another directive.  The controller function of a directive is basically its API. So, if you require another directive in your directive, the controller function of the required directive is injected as the fourth parameter to your link function.

So, in your example, the controller function for `myParentController` will be injected as the fourth argument to your link function, so you'd define it like this:

```
link : function (scope, element, attrs, myParentController)
```

Then, in your directive doing the requiring, you can access any functions that were defined on the controller function of the controller you're requiring.

Hope that helps.